# Showing a list of a process's threads using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to get a list of a process's threads and a way to suspend those threads,
I have been searching for a week now and I can't seem to be able to find a way to do that.

I'm trying to list threads of another process the way Process Hacker does :
[Process Hacker process thread list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dws6D.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far and what results are you getting?

Comment: @AndrewMortimer. So far I've been able to suspend the process itself, I can't find a proper guide to threads within a process.

Comment: Process Hacker is open source so you can look at how it does it in the source code. You might find [pinvoke.net](https://pinvoke.net/) useful for the calls.